# How to search for a DNA sequence in a genome on ENA (European Nucleotide Archive)?

Tags: genetics, bioinformatics

I have to do a search for small DNA sequences in the genome of an organism in ENA. I have the accession number and project id. However, I can't download the whole genome because of the download size and would prefer to do it online if possible. I have a rough idea of the part of the genome I wish to scan in, don't know if that's relevant.

Comment: Do you want an exact match? Did you try BLAST? You can adjust the parameters according to your needs.

Comment: Have you already tried to submit accession number into advanced search? https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/data/warehouse/search

Comment: @WYSIWYG Yes I  do need exact matches. BLAST would search it against multiple sequences wouldn't it? I don't see how you can find DNA sequences in a particular genome using it

Answer (score 2):

While it is much better/easier to download and do the exact search on your own, it is possible to do something similar, online. You can use NCBI-BLAST and increase the word length and mismatch/gap penalty. It also allows restricting the subject space; you can even [align two sequences](https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?PAGE_TYPE=BlastSearch&BLAST_SPEC=blast2seq&LINK_LOC=align2seq). The BLAST on ENA does not have much flexibility (subject restriction/word length). Perhaps you can look for a duplicate sequence on NCBI.

If this genome is available on UCSC genome browser then you can use [BLAT](https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgBlat) too. However, it only accepts sequences larger than 19nt.